# SAP Fiori Group Name Change not reflecting in Fiori Launchpad in Qulaity System

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-basis

I changed our group name in Development and Transported to Quality System. But in quality system old name is reflecting.

I checked designer Fiori in Quality System. Group name Change is reflecting there but in SAP Fiori Launchpad it is not reflecting.

I tried to clear cache using below T-Codes in Quality System also but same issue

- `/UI2/INVALIDATE_CLIENT_CACHES`
- `/UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES`
- `/IWFND/CACHE_CLEANUP`
- `/IWBEP/CACHE_CLEANUP`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you made sure you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: Yes! I cleared the browser cache also. And also tried to run the application in Incognito Mode but issue is same

Answer (score 0):

In the SAP help documentation, there is a chapter called "Cache Buster for SAP Fiori": https://help.sap.com/viewer/a7b390faab1140c087b8926571e942b7/7.4.19/en-US/a1e56ed27d2f48b8bfed95bd80a23d88.html

In the chapter, it says:
“To identify updated applications, the SAP Fiori launchpad uses the SAPUI5 application index on the ABAP front-end server.
The SAPUI5 application index itself is updated by the ABAP program *Calculation of SAPUI5 Application Index for SAPUI5 Repositories* (/UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE).
We recommend that you schedule this program to run at regular intervals.”

Maybe this will solve your problem?

Comment: I tried to execute this Program also but story is same. Everywhere change in the Group is reflecting apart from Fiori Launchpad. Don't know exactly why it is not reflecting in Fiori Launchpad. I read many blogs & documentation and executed it but story is still same

Comment: Just to make sure:
The question is related to FLP Groups names, which are maintained in the FLP Designer?
In this case, usually executing /UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES should solve the issue.
Please check the CUST layer of FLPD, as this layer is used at runtime.

Another reason could be that this group has been personalized in FLP and therefore does not get the update name.
In that case, you need to re-set the group in FLP and check again.